# Neo4j jexp/batch-import weird error: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: csv, neo4j, data-import

I'm trying to import around 6M nodes using Michael Hunger's batch importer but I'm getting this weird error: 
`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "78rftark42lp5f8nadc63l62r3" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)`

It is weird because `78rftark42lp5f8nadc63l62r3` is the very first value of the big CSV file  that I'm trying to import and its datatype is set to string.

These are the first three lines of that file:

```
name:string:sessions    labels:label    timestamp:long:timestamps   visitor_pid referrer_url
78rftark42lp5f8nadc63l62r3  Session 1401277353000   cd7b76ef09b498e95b35b49de2925c5f    http://someurl.com/blah?t=123                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
dt2gshq5pao8fg7bka8fdri123  Session 1401277329000   4036ac507698e4daf2ada98664da6d58    http://enter.url.com/signup/signup.php
```

As you can see here `name:string:session` the datatype of that column is set to `string`, why is the importer trying to parse the value as `long`?

I'm completely new to Neo4j and its ecosystem so I'm sure I'm missing something here.

This is the command I ran to import a bunch of nodes and relations:
  `./import.sh \
  -db-directory sessions.db \
  -nodes "toImport/browser-nodes.csv.gz,toImport/country-nodes.csv.gz,toImport/device-nodes.csv.gz,toImport/ip-nodes.csv.gz,toImport/language-nodes.csv.gz,toImport/operatingSystem-nodes.csv.gz,toImport/referrerType-nodes.csv.gz,toImport/resolution-nodes.csv.gz,toImport/session-nodes.csv" \
  -rels "toImport/rel-session-browser.csv.gz,toImport/rel-session-country.csv.gz,toImport/rel-session-device.csv.gz,toImport/rel-session-ip.csv.gz,toImport/rel-session-language.csv.gz,toImport/rel-session-operatingSystem.csv.gz,toImport/rel-session-referrerType.csv.gz,toImport/rel-session-resolution.csv.gz"`

The file that fails is the last one in the list of nodes `toImport/session-nodes.csv`
The other files were successfully processed by the importer.

This is the content of the `batch.properties` file:

```
dump_configuration=false
cache_type=none
use_memory_mapped_buffers=true
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=1G
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=3G
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=1G
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=1G
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=1G
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=1G
batch_import.node_index.sessions=exact
batch_import.node_index.browsers=exact
batch_import.node_index.operatingsystems=exact
batch_import.node_index.referrertypes=exact
batch_import.node_index.devices=exact
batch_import.node_index.resolutions=exact
batch_import.node_index.countries=exact
batch_import.node_index.languages=exact
batch_import.node_index.ips=exact
batch_import.node_index.timestamps=exact
```

Any thoughts? 
I can't see what's the problem here so any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
I'm using this binary:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14493611/batch_importer_20.zip

Comment: Can you share your real file? I think perhaps your delimiters are wrong (not real tabs or spaces in there somewhere?) Also perhaps you use that value somewhere else in the file?

Comment: Hi Michael, I've re-generated the CSV files again and the error is gone. Now I'm getting this error when importing the relations: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8rik5aqtisg0cash6313lmhr66"`.  It looks like the importer expects the Node ID and not an indexed property, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here but [I used the format of the sample file to create the files for the relations](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/blob/2.1/sample/rels.csv).  You can [grab a copy of my files here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eu1j5oua4hfubng/batch_importer_2.1_plus_data.zip).

Comment: This is the command I ran `./import.sh -db-directory sessions.db -nodes "data/sessions.tsv,data/devices.tsv,data/oses.tsv,data/browsers.tsv,data/ips.tsv,data/countries.tsv,data/languages.tsv,data/resolutions.tsv" -rels "data/rel-devices.tsv,data/rel-oses.tsv,data/browsers.tsv,data/ips.tsv,data/countries.tsv,data/languages.tsv,data/resolutions.tsv"` the error pops up when the importer tries to import `data/rel-devices.tsv` which is the first file in the list of relation files.

Comment: Adolfo, this is weird, lemme fix the binary, I think things got messed, up thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Should be fixed, now. Sorry, my bad. Please note that it has a different syntax, the future version for 2.1+ got mixed up with that download.

Comment: ok, great! thanks Michael. Should I download [this binary for 2.0](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14493611/batch_importer_20.zip) again? or is it there a new binary for 2.1? What do you mean by "it has a different syntax"? I can't find any new commit or documentation update in [your github repo](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/2.1)  Oh, btw, please answer the question with your response so I can flag this question as answered! :)