# neo4j batch importer NumberFormatException

Tags: neo4j

I am using superfast-batch-importer for neo4j.
When importing the legacy indexing example's relationship file.. 
in the first line itself ....i got a NumberFormatException...

[Neo4j jexp/batch-import weird error: java.lang.NumberFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24422083/neo4j-jexp-batch-import-weird-error-java-lang-numberformatexception)
This questions talks about the issue.. but i dont see the fixes yet in the code

Can someone please let me know where to take the right binary if this is fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use that one, use the normal github.com/jexp/batch-import for 2.1 or wait for 2.2 milestone for something out of the box.

The superfast is not production ready and was known to create inconsistent stores.

Comment: when is 2.2 milestone expected?

Comment: Some time in November.